# How to create an cordova application that refers a external file for URL?

Tags: html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-jet

I need to create an application that should refer an external file for url.
The external file should be manually edited by the user in case of change in URL.

The application should deployed for both ios and android application.

please suggest any other method like create preferences variables that can edited by user

Answer (score 0):

You can create page with a from (with your preferences) and save the date from the form in your localStorage. The **localStorage** has no expiration date but will be lost when the user removes the app from his device.

The localStorage is a part of **Web Storage API** which is supported by all modern/major browsers ([proof](https://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)). Since cordova actually serves your app as a web page you can use the Web Storage API as well ([cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html))
Documentation info about localStorage can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)